# Regex application against IP ranges in IPv6 format

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am having a pandas dataframe with structure [2 rows x 3 columns] and needing in loop to apply regex for each row within same column

That column contains bunch of IP ranges where I need to get rid of the ones in IPv6 format with such syntax:

`[\n  "4.150.35.64/27",\n "51.120.40.208/30",\n "191.233.8.22/31",\n "2603:1020:5:1::5e0/123",\n "2603:1040:d04::600/122" \n]`

The aim is therefore to remove last two entries removing also last comma ending up with:

`[\n  "4.150.35.64/27",\n "51.120.40.208/30",\n "191.233.8.22/31" \n]`

How to accomplish this?

Comment: You'd better off using the built-in [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module.